Has anyone tried reworking Aristotle’s Logic in terms of Category Theory?
Has anyone tried reworking Aristotle’s Logic in terms of Category Theory? I ask because it seems easy to do. All we have to do is interpret “is” or “are” as an arrow. So, all As are Bs can be formalized ∀A(A→B). Some As are Bs can be formalized as ∃A(A→B). No A is B can be formalized as ∀A(A→B^C ). Some As are not Bs can be formalized as ∃A(A→B^C ).

Man, that would be really confusing. What would "category" mean in such a study when it means something different in both areas?

Your toy example is pretty static and quantification over A is really type theory as the foundation of modern Category Theory where the Hom arrows (morphisms) between objects in a same category could be said to be dynamic dependent types assigned to each pair of  different objects and a category or functor are themselves dependent types conceivably along with the important univalent identity type. You could also levitate higher to n-category or ∞-category after defining arrows between arrows as n-arrows where types inherently have high-dimensional structures such as in homotopy theory...

@LorenzoGilBadiola And where are the categories, their objects, the Hom-sets, the functors and theis adjoints, the products and coproducts, etc. - How familiar are you with Category Theory? -  A possible reference: Saunders Mac Lane and Ieke Moerdijk: Sheaves in Geometry and Logic, A First Introduction to Topos Theory.

@JoWehler, I know a little bit about it. But the terminology seems so confusing.

@LorentoGilBadiola A classical introduction is "Saunders Mac Lane: Categories for the Working Mathematician". To benefit from category theory presupposes some knowledge about the category of sets, vector spaces, groups, topological spaces. Otherwise it looks like so called "General nonsense".

Yes, I thought about this a few years ago. I imagine
other people have as well. The category you describe is simply a preorder, i.e., a small category in which, for every pair of objects X,Y, there exists at most one morphism from X to Y. To put it another way, a preorder is a set equipped with a reflexive, transitive binary relation. (The relation is not necessarily antisymmetric, so a preorder is not necessarily a partially-ordered set.)
I cleaned up most of the Latex markup from my notes from several years ago (since Phil.SE doesn't support Latex), and I'll paste the most relevant part of my notes below. No promises about how readable it'll be. I think there are no surprises in the ideas described there. After the part I'm pasting below, looks like my notes continue, considering the set of all functions from a "material-syllogistic calculus" to the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of a finite classical propositional logic. The claim is that that set of functions forms a commutative Boolean bialgebroid, i.e., an internal category in the opposite category of Boolean algebras. As I recall, I tested out the usual things that mathematicians do with commutative bialgebroids (representations, cohomology, geometry of the associated stack), and none of them seemed like they yielded any philosophically meaningful results.
In fact this whole train of thought seemed to me like it didn't yield any philosophical insights, which is why I didn't pursue the idea any further.
My notes are below.

Let A be the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of some classical propositional calculus, and suppose we want to augment the propositional calculus with some additional information that encodes that, in a model M for the augmented propositional calculus, certain of the propositions are actually material predications, i.e., propositions of the form "A is B" for some objects A and B. Nothing about what these "objects" actually are is to be encoded in the propositional calculus: instead we want to understand what structure one has on the propositional calculus, and on its Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra, as a consequence of certain propositions being material predications.
In general we do not have a Boolean algebra of the material predications themselves: the conjunction of two material predications may or may not be logically equivalent to a material predication. For example, while the conjunction of "Socrates is Greek" and "Socrates is male" is logically equivalent to the material predication "Socrates is male and Greek", the conjunction of "Socrates is Greek" and "Aristotle is male" is not for formal reasons logically equivalent to a single material predication at all.
Similarly we cannot necessarily take the disjunction of two material predications and expect to have a material predication, even up to logical equivalence. So we do not have binary Boolean operations v and \wedge on the collection of material predications.
While we do not have Boolean operations on the material predications, we do have a certain kind of operation on them which encodes syllogistic inference: given two material predications P = "A is B" and Q = "B is C", we ought to have a third proposition R = "A is C," and we ought to have P \wedge Q -> R. We would like to think of R as a "syllogistic composite" of P and Q, and we would like to think of the process of syllogistically composing P and Q to yield R as "syllogistic inference." The problem is that, if we are simply given two propositions P and Q in a propositional calculus, unless we have some additional data, we do not know whether P and Q are material predications, so P and Q may not have a syllogistic composite; and if P and Q are indeed each material predications, we still do not have a syllogistic composite of P with Q unless the object of P coincides with the subject of Q. That is, we do not have a syllogistic composite of "A is B" with "C is D" unless B = C (or, if we are willing to swap the order of the propositions, A=D).
These considerations make us understand that we cannot ask for composition of syllogisms to give us a well-defined product A x A -> A on the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra A of our propositional calculus, or even on the collection of propositions in the propositional calculus itself.
Motivating question: What kind of well-behaved structure on A could we consider which does encode composition of syllogisms?
The answer to the motivating question is straightforward if we are willing to be precise about exactly what a material-syllogistic calculus ought to be. By a material-syllogistic calculus we mean a set T of terms and a primitive binary relation on terms, written is, satisfying the rules:

(Reflexivity) A is A for all A.
(Transitivity) If A is B and B is C, then A is C.

From the definitions, it is clear that every material-syllogistic calculus is a preorder. In this naive sense, preorders provide an order-theoretic semantics for material-syllogistic calculuses.
In these notes, we consider only material-syllogistic calculuses, i.e., those in which all predictions are material predications. Given a pair of terms (t_1,t_2) in such a calculus, there exists at most one predication whose subject is t_1 and whose object is t_2; i.e., either t_1 is t_2, or it isn't.
Of course, in an arbitrary small category, there might be more than one morphism with a given domain and with a given codomain, i.e., in the associated internal category there may be pairs (t_1,t_2)\in T x T such that there is more than one element m such that s(m) = t_1 and o(m) = t_2. One expects this kind of behavior to arise from typed syllogistic calculuses, i.e., calculuses in which there is more than one type of predication. Typed syllogistic calculuses were already considered at the very beginning of the subject, as in the two-typed syllogistic calculus in Aristotle's Categories, with relations of type "is said of" and of type "is present in."
